# JRate How to get value from selected star and store it in database using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get value from Jrate Plugin for example when the using click on 3rd start the value should i get should must be 3.and i can get it on using jRate onSet option
Here is my HTML

```
<div id="jRate"></div>
```

And My Javascript is

```
  $("#jRate").jRate({
        onSet: function(rating) {
                   alert("Selected Rating: "+rating);
             }
    });
```

but i dont want to get the value on onSet function i want value when user click on save button  just like how we get value from inout box

```
$('#inputbox').val();
```

Is their any way i can get value like this..

Comment: Show some HTML. Where is the HTML that has the value ratings?

Comment: I have edited the question JRate is a plugin we only need a div for it with a id. @AmmarCSE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to set a custom attribute. You can do this on the `#jRate` element

```
$("#jRate").jRate({
        onSet: function(rating) {
                   $("#jRate").attr("data-rating", rating);
             }
    });
```

then, later in the `click` handler

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var rating = $("#jRate").attr("data-rating");
});
```

Comment: var rating = $("#jRate").attr("data-rating"); is giving me undefined in the console.

Comment: @usama, did you set the rating first?

Comment: yes i set the ratting first the problem is the jRate is SVG based... so it is showing me undefined.

Comment: @usama, can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: can you help me how should i use $(document) with JRate plugin  with this code   $(".jRate").jRate({
           onSet: function(rating) {
                      alert(rating)
               }
       });

Comment: No @AmmarCSE kindly look at my this question i have explained this better on my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416417/jquery-is-not-working-on-newly-added-elements-to-the-dom-with-plugin-like-jrate

Comment: The code which you have given me is working totaly fine when page is loaded by default but it is not working i append the div through jquery using dom...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78611/discussion-between-ammarcse-and-usama).