# Jquery is not working on newly added elements to the dom with Plugin like JRate Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have been searching this on internet, I have found some answers which were helpful like but they were not enough to solve my problem (e.g. 
[Similar Problem but no solution provided for my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537323/jquery-function-not-binding-to-newly-added-dom-elements))

I am using **JRate** plugin, I am adding a `div` inside a `div` using jQuery. The problem is that when I add it using jQuery and use the JRate Functions then they are not working. But they are working without appending a new `div`.

I know how to make it work. I will have to use `$(document)` but I dont know how to use it with this code.

Here is HTML

```
<div class="jRate"></div>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
$(".jRate").jRate({
    onSet: function(rating) {                             
        alert(rating);
    }
});
```

Here is my appending code

```
var divjRate = "<div class='jRate'></div>";
$(divjRate).appendTo('.fb-jRate');
```

Can any one tell me how can I use `$(document)` here or any other alternative solution you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the html element first so that it is registered in the `DOM`. Then, you can call `jRate` on it

```
var divjRate = "<div><div class='jRate'></div></div>";

// Append new element to container of choice
$(divjRate).appendTo('.fb-jRate');

// Use plugin on new element
$('.jRate').jRate({
    onSet: function(rating) {                            
        alert(rating);
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, next step. I need to reproduce it. Can you put it up in a fiddle or give me a site you are using it on?

Comment: when you say it is not working, do you mean it draws the stars but onSet is not working? Or does it give an error?

Comment: it draws the stars but onSet is not working and it deos not give any error

Comment: is their a way i can reset the star to 0 on using jquery so that i don't have to append a new one in the body

Comment: @usama, can you get it in a fiddle or somehow give me an example to play with?

Comment: I am trying to get it in a fiddle but thier is no cdn provide by the site http://www.toolitup.com/jRate.html  so fiddle is not working.. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78613/discussion-between-ammarcse-and-usama).

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have linked applies to binding event listeners, which is not the case with a typical jQuery plugin that usually involves DOM replacement and other things.

You will need to apply the method to newly added DOM elements. The DOM mutation event specification is deprecated due to performance issues, and it is not realistic to expect the browser to keep track of all changes (and what kind of changes) happening in the DOM.

For example, if you're adding new content with an AJAX call, you can apply the method to newly added content within the `jqXHR.done()` function.

---

**Update**: OP provided with some code, so I have adding a way to initialize the plugin for newly added DOM element:

```
// Declare new element
var divjRate = "<div><div class='jRate'></div></div>";

// Use plugin on new element
$(divjRate).find('.jRate').jRate({
    onSet: function(rating) {                            
        alert(rating);
    }
});

// Append new element to container of choice
$(divjRate).appendTo('.fb-jRate');
```

Comment: here is my appending code now can you tell how can i make it work  var divjRate = "<div class='jRate'></div>";
  $(divjRate).appendTo('.fb-jRate');

Comment: @usama Might be because of a selector issue. Try my updated answer now.

Comment: it is still not working after the updated answer... :(